# AngularJS $http don't trigger digest loop

Tags: angularjs, http, angularjs-digest

I have an issue with angular digest loop. When I do a http call and put response in $scope, that var is not updated on view until next digest loop.

E.g. I have the folliwing call wrapped into function and button on view which calls function using ng-click. First time when I click the button, nothing is happened on view (http response sent and response is received). After clicking the button for the second time, view is updated with data from previus response and current response is updated after the next click etc...

```
$scope.loadItems = function(){
   ItemService.getData().then(function(rsp) {
      $scope.items = rsp.data;
    });
}
```

ItemService.getData() is basically wrapping $http call:

```
getData : function(){
    return $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/api/items'
    });
}
```

And html

```
<button ng-click="loadItems()">Load</button>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can we see the code for ItemService.getData()?  Also, the entire function code that is called from ng-click.

Comment: It would be nice to see more. Maybe post the controller you use and the corrsponding part of the HTML.

Comment: I updated info for html and service

Comment: @DušanStanković, did you manage to find a solution to your problem? If yes, could you please share it with us? I am quite interested in what was the problem and it might help other users as well.

Comment: Issue was that $http was injected wrongly and it didn't trigger digest loop on it's own.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I guess the problem is the following. I bet you use the $scope.items in an ng-repeat, do you? e.g.

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items">
        //Here goes my little item
    </li>
</ul>
```

Right? Well, there is a problem. The ng-repeat takes a reference to the "items" collection and once the referenced collection is changed, the HTML is updated. But ... The problem of doing

```
$scope.items = rsp.data;
```

is that you assign to the "items" a brand new collection which is NOT referenced by the ng-repeat - it still references the old one which was not changed. Therefore the following should work - use a dot in your $scope.

**Controller:**

```
$scope.data = {};

ItemService.getData().then(function(rsp) {
    $scope.data.items = rsp.data;
});
```

**View:**

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in data.items">
        //Here goes my little item
    </li>
</ul>
```

In another words, the problem is not in calling the digest cycle - it IS called. The problem is in misuse of the $scope.

**[This link](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes#ng-repeat)** should be helpful. It explains the scope nuances in more details.

Comment: This is happening globally, on evry http request, so I should do it on every http request I have. Any other solutions? P.S. it also works wrapped in $timout

Comment: You can watch the $scope.items.

Comment: @DušanStanković , please see my updated answer. I guess I answered in a bit hurry at first ...

Comment: Also, this is already done, my guess it's something with http, any idea why this is done outside of scope.apply?

Comment: No clue, I am sorry. I could not see a reason why it would be called outside of the scope apply.

Comment: Can somehow intereptors or something else influence this?

Answer (score -1):

You need to change getData() to look like this:

```
getData: function() {
  return $http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/api/items'
  }).then(function(response) {
    return response.data;
  }, function(error) {
    return error;
  });
}
```

and $scope.loadItems() to

```
$scope.loadItems = function(){
   ItemService.getData().then(function(rsp) {
      $scope.items = rsp;
    });
}
```

Comment: No, that is not necessary, he can return the promise and call the "then" method in the client's code calling the service method - exactly as he does.